# ETX character cropping response in IIS Express - at 666 characters

Tags: asp-classic, iis-express, iis-8

My output seems to be cropped in IIS Express (8.0) when running classic asp.

I'm guessing it's a very long line that is being cropped at the response.

The same classic asp appears to be working ok in IIS6 on Windows Server 2003. Notably it is still cropped in the network profiler (F12 tools), but copying to a text editor it's not cropped.

However the very very strange this is that the ETX is inserted at exactly 666 characters (including white space).

[image: Screen shot of response in notepad++ depicting ETX character at 666 characters]

I can't find a reference to maximum line lengths in IIS Express.

EDIT:

To clarify, I was wondering why the response is being cropped by the ETX character and why it was at exactly 666 characters.

Comment: btw I think this is hilarious :-) I love a tasty Easter egg. But I'm wondering if it's documented anywhere about response limits.

Comment: The plot thickens - it was probably just random that it was 666 - I'm simply working on a devil of a bug!

Comment: Hello downvoter, I have added clarification to what I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loooots of diagnosis.

Watching everything go back and forth with a variety of profilers and attaching debugger, I can see a little "L" being returned by our vbscript data layer. The column in question is ntext. The little "L" copied from the debugger into a plaintext editor revealed the infamous ETX character.

The ETX character seems to tell classic asp to flush the response instantly and not continue with the processing of the page.

I can only assume that there is a compatibility problem with running SQL Server 2012 Local DB and ADODB. Especially as I had to come up with workarounds to get it to work in the first place i.e. an ODBC connection using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 then connecting the classic asp to a DSN. As SQL Server Native Client 11.0 by itself in classic asp couldn't handle NOCOUNT being OFF and PRINT statements.

It's a long shot getting everything working together (after lots of experimenting with ADO, this is the best option so far), so it's understandable that there would be (very) odd compatibility problems.

Fortunately this is just a developer workstation, so nothing to worry about in production.